# Query IP Country Using Hosted/Mirrored Regional Internet Registry IP Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ip

I want to query these IP blocks, which I've already curl/parsed/trimmed/inserted into a single mysql database table on my server:

- ARIN (US REGISTRY) ROOT FOLDER: ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/

  - ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/ripencc/delegated-ripencc-latest
  - ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/lacnic/delegated-lacnic-latest
  - ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/arin/delegated-arin-latest
  - ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/apnic/delegated-apnic-latest
  - ftp://ftp.arin.net/pub/stats/afrinic/delegated-afrinic-latest

Specification (and table column structure):

**registry|cc|type|start|value|date|status**

https://www.apnic.net/publications/media-library/documents/resource-guidelines/rir-statistics-exchange-format#FileHeader

**Question) How do I input an individual IP address, and return a 2-character ISO 3166 country code?**

I've tried writing queries for this. But I don't really understand what "start" means...or at least how to relate it to some kind of "end" for the IP block range.

In the past, I've queried the long-form of the IP address against a High/Low or From/To range.

If it is at all helpful, I have the following php functions that I've used in the past to convert IP addresses to long-form integers:

```
//Convert IPv6 address into long form number
function ip6_to_ipnumber($ip_address) {
  $pton = @inet_pton($ip_address);
  if (!$pton) { return false; }
  $number = '';
  foreach (unpack('C*', $pton) as $byte) {
    $number .= str_pad(decbin($byte), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }
  return base_convert(ltrim($number, '0'), 2, 10);
}

//Convert IPv4 address into long form number
function ip4_to_ipnumber($ip_address) {
  return ip2long($ip_address);
}

//Identify the IP address version
function ip_version($ip_address) {
     return strpos($ip_address, ":") === false ? 4 : 6;
}
```

---

For me to accept for bounty:

> 1. Explain how solution works.
> 2. Query answer must work for both IPv4 and IPv6, and return a single country ISO 3166 code.
> 3. Must be able to query data from all 5 registry regions simultaneously.
> 4. If MySql query of table in raw form won't work, explain the changes required to table structure (such as converting to long-form integers).
>
> Essentially, I'm looking for a **solution to geo-locate IP address countries** based on the latest public-domain ip-block data from the regional registries.

This solution would probably be useful to a lot of people. Good luck, and thanks for your help guys!

Comment: "Start" appears to be the first IP in the block referenced by each row.  I'm not sure what your ultimate purpose here is but [there's a simpler, and probably more accurate way to associate IP addresses with countries](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2).  (I have no affiliation with that product, btw).

Comment: I see no reason to pay money to a third party supplier for IP block information that is in the **public domain**. It seems to me that certain companies are making an absolute killing based on the fact that 99% of people don't realise that this is public information. Thanks, but I'm not looking for Lite databases or APIs.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's the start of the block. But what is the end of the block? And why do the IP ranges of the other RIR's blocks appear to overlap with each other? In previous implementations I've converted an IP to it's long-form (I have made functions to do this) and then queried to compare against "low" and "high" values.

Answer (score -1):

hi i'm research about your problem with this
and i send to email to have information but the factorys of these services have not support by this.
but if you can watch your links the pages is a remote file (name_file.text)
if you can use this file for you , use

```
 $content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $content;
```

if you try with this you can read the url (remote file)

for more information about this you can check this link

[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

you can fin more information about read each part of file and use how you need

```
file() - Reads entire file into an array
fgets() - Gets line from file pointer
fread() - Binary-safe file read
readfile() - Outputs a file
file_put_contents() - Write a string to a file
stream_get_contents() - Reads remainder of a stream into a string
stream_context_create() - Creates a stream context
$http_response_header
```

Comment: Thanks, but this question refers to IP blocks, not how to read the files. As I mentioned in the question I already have parsed and inserted all the data successfully into my database :)

Comment: i don;t undestand you need make query on your database ? fot get the ip  that parsed and inserted on the same database ?

Comment: This is a database of IP blocks from the Regional Internet Registries. It covers ranges of IP addresses - billions of addresses. Specific IP addresses are not listed. I am developing my own native country geo-location system.

Comment: if do you would like you can send me a email for talk about your project , is very interesting if do you like i can help you with some one ideas .. i'm working with millions records and rest services php, mysql and some one languages, diegoavila@informaticos.com...good luck